# strace output problems solve

Tags: linux, strace

I tried to run `strace` in linux for my Program.

Here is the example Output :

```
brk(0)                                  = 0x804b000
brk(0x806c000)                          = 0x806c000
open("test.txt", O_RDONLY)              = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=216, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7728000
read(3, "10\n10\n2\t3\t3\t5\t4\t7\t7\t2\t2\t7\t\n8\t3\t1"..., 4096) = 216
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb7728000, 4096)                = 0
**open(NULL, O_RDONLY)                    = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)**
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl64(3, F_GETFL)                     = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb7728000
**_llseek(3, 0, 0xbfc97a44, SEEK_CUR)     = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)**
write(3, "Can't open file!: Bad address\n", 30Can't open file!: Bad address
```

Why i get some errors in that two line. what `**open(NULL, O_RDONLY)**` does it means?

Comment: You are opening a file whose name is NULL. At least the filename containing variable is NULL

Answer (score 3):

```
**open(NULL, O_RDONLY)
```

You're passing a NULL string as file name.  According to the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), `EFAULT` is generated when the pathname points outside your accessible address space.

```
_llseek(3, 0, 0xbfc97a44, SEEK_CUR)
```

You are trying to set the offset of a file descriptor which does not support this function.

In fact, you are trying to move the offset of the STANDARD ERROR (3 is the result of dup(2)), which does not make sense as it is not a real file. According to the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html), `ESPIPE` is generated when a file descriptor is associated with a pipe, socket, or FIFO.